# Converting a text file to list and then reading list to determine if an entry is within the list

Tags: python, list, text

I'm having a little trouble with converting a text file to a list.
the text file is presented like this:

```
5658845
4520125
7895122
8777541
8451277
1302850
8080152
```

I have written code that takes user input and tries to determine if the user input is in the list. I am however having some trouble in searching the list as I can only get a result on the last result in the list, where am I going wrong?

```
def accountReader():

    while True:
        chargeInput = (raw_input ("Enter a charge account to be validated: "))
        if chargeInput == '':
            break
            sys.exit


        else:
            chargeAccount = open('charge_accounts.txt', 'r')
            line = chargeAccount.readline()
            while line != '':
                if chargeInput == line:
                    print chargeInput, 'was found in list.'                    
                else:
                    print chargeInput, 'not found in list.'
                    break           


    chargeFile.close
```

Comment: There's a `chargeFile` closed at the end, but never opened; `chargeAccount` is opened but never closed. Is this really the code you've got problems with? :) Trying to debug retyping-problems isn't much fun. Copy-n-paste is king. :)

Comment: oh sorry brain is a bit addled at the moment, been going in circles with this code and its a bit chop and changed as i have tried alternate solutions. The chargefile.close is actually chargeAccount.close in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A line-by-line breakdown:

```
def accountReader():

    while True:
        chargeInput = (raw_input ("Enter a charge account to be validated: "))
        if chargeInput == '':
            break
            sys.exit
```

Ok, so far so good. You've created a loop that repeatedly asks the user for input and breaks when the user inputs nothing.

```
        else:
            chargeAccount = open('charge_accounts.txt', 'r')
            line = chargeAccount.readline()
```

Here's where you start running into problems. `readline` reads a single line from `chargeAccount` and stores it in `line`. That means you can only test one line!

```
            while line != '':
                if chargeInput == line:
                    print chargeInput, 'was found in list.'
```

This further compounds your problem. If `chargeInput == line`, then this prints a message and then the loop repeats. Since there's nothing to break out of the loop, this will result in an infinite loop that constantly tests one single line from the file. Also, because each line from the file ends with a newline (`\n`), `chargeInput == line` will always yield false (thanks Steven Rumbalski for reminding me of this). Use `.strip()` (as suggested in matchw's answer), or, if you can tolerate partial matches, you could use Python's simple substring matching functionality: `if chargeInput in line`.

```
                else:
                    print chargeInput, 'not found in list.'
                    break           


    chargeFile.close
```

And here, as sarnold pointed out, you've misnamed your file; furthermore, it's in a completely different block of code, which means that you repeatedly open `chargeAccount` files without closing any of them.

As you can see from matchw's post, there is a much simpler way to do what you're trying to do. But I think you'd do well to figure out how to write this code correctly in the style you've chosen. I'll give you one hint: there should be a `line = chargeAccount.readline()` *inside* the innermost while loop. Do you see why? Also, you should probably exit the loop when you *succeed* in finding a match, not when you fail. Then you should think about a way to test whether the search was a success after the innermost loop has completed.

Comment: One additional problem.  `line` ends with a newline, whereas chargeInput doesn't, meaning that even if he was comparing every value, they would never be the match.

Answer (score 2):

i would read the list like this

```
chargeAccount = open('charge_accounts.txt', 'r')
accts = [line.strip() for line in chareAccount]

if chareInput in accts:
  #do something
else:
  #do something else
```

at the very least .strip() off the readline(), your line likely looks like '5658845\n'

**UPDATE**

so after testing what you have with my modification it works....except it repeats indef do to the while acct != ''

here is what  I changed

```
chargeAccount = open('charge_accounts.txt', 'r')
  accts = [line.strip() for line in chargeAccount]
  while accts != '':
     if chargeInput in accts:
        #...
```

I would ditch the while loop altogether, it is either in the list or its not. no need to cycle through each line.